# C# Sendkeys class {SHIFT}

Tags: c#, shift, sendkeys

I am trying to use the Sendkeys class to send a SHIFT key. But it doesn't allow for SHIFT. Only BACKSPACE or ENTER or basically anything but SHIFT. I need a way to send shift keys, like, Sendkeys.Send({SHIFT});

Is there a way to do this? Is there another way to send SHIFTs?

Comment: I mean shift by itself @GrantWinney

Answer (score 3):

%() sends just the Alt command.  So I assume that +() will send just the shift key.  However I cannot think of a way to test this, since the shift key does nothing by itself.  pressing shift 5 times normally prompts if you want to turn on sticky keys, but +()+()+()+()+() does not prompt for sticky keys.

Read the senction just after it explains how to send F1 to F12: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278655.aspx

```
%A = Alt+A
%(AE) = Alt+A+E
%()AE = ALT,A,E
```